# Prestashop v1.7.5.1 'Add to cart' slow with very high TTFB

Tags: php, performance, profiling, prestashop

We have a shop that runs on Prestashop v1.7.5.1 and the site becomes extremely slow once we add a product to the cart. Also, when we apply a coupon it takes about 10-20 seconds to apply it.

**What we tried**
We enabled CDN (cloudflare) , we also enabled server side caching. In the Prestashop the CCC is enabled for HTML & JS & CSS and we now have enabled the CacheMemcache. However, none of this seems to fix the slow checkout process. Ajax cart  is enabled but still customers are reporting 10-25 seconds to complete each step.

We then tried to enabled the profiler and found strange values. So, we are guessing it is something wrong with the theme itself.

Since the log is huge. We are sharing few value. We need help understanding what does these values mean.

**Profiling numbers from the site are below**

```
Querying Time   6119 ms  
Queries 1821   
Memory Peak Usage   47.0 Mb  
Included Files  625 files - 8.66 Mb  
PrestaShop Cache    0.01 Mb  
Global vars 0.38 Mb
```

**Top 5 Table Stress**

```
912 category_lang  
900 category  
673 category_shop  
193 creativepage_meta  
124 cart_product
```

**ObjectModel instances**

```
Name Instance Source  
Category    1554 /modules/posmegamenu/posmegamenu.php
CartRule    50 /classes/Cart.php
Carrier 22 /classes/Cart.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your menu can provoke the issue. Try to disable it and test your store again

Comment: I have tried doing it but that changed nothing. I am going to try it disabling it along with disabling the cache. And see if it helps.

Comment: It didn't help. It still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: I have posted some more details about my hosting and setup on presta forum, you can check it here https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1025339-add-to-cart-extremly-slow-and-high-ttfb-profiling-shows-2000-queries-1000-table-stress/?do=findComment&comment=3243791